# How can I debug OAuth2 Authentication flow in a (Firefox) WebExtension?

Tags: javascript, oauth, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have written a `WebExtension` addon for Firefox that authenticates with some external API. The extension has worked fine for a while, but suddenly the authentication flow is broken. The login page of the service is displayed fine, I can login, and the page calls the `redirect_uri` of my extension (at least I can see a request to that URI in the browser status bar). The login popup then closes. However, the promise of my extension is never fulfilled and no error message is displayed.

```
const REDIRECT_URL = browser.identity.getRedirectURL();
const SECRET = "MY_SECRET";
const CLIENT_ID = "MY_ID";
const AUTH_URL = `https://API_URL/authorize?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&response_type=token&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(REDIRECT_URL)}&scope=all`;

function extractAccessToken(redirectUri) {
    // never called...
}

function authorize() {
    return browser.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
        interactive: true,
        url: AUTH_URL
    });
}

function getAccessToken() {
    return authorize().then(extractAccessToken);
}
```

Above is my authentication code. `extractAccessToken` is never called and nothing really happens on the client side, although I'm pretty sure that authentication succeeded. How can I debug at which step things are going wrong?

---

Edit: The WebExtension `redirect_uri` is something like `https://ID.extensions.allizom.org` and if I simply try to type it into my browser's address bar I'm getting 404. Are the mozilla servers maybe offline?